# In a definite integral, as we allowed to use the same symbol in the upper/lower bound of the integration as the variable of the integrated function?

Tags: definite-integrals, notation

Occassionally I see the notation
$$\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin x\mathrm{d}x$$
and some author will avoid using $x$ as the variable of the integrated function by writting 
$$\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin t\mathrm{d}t.$$

My question is, is there anything wrong with writing $\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin x\mathrm{d}x$？

Comment: Technically it is permitted, and yields a well-defined expression, but I think it is always more confusing than the version that uses different variables. Why not write you math in a way that makes it easier for your readers to understand?

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to write
\begin{align*}
\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
This is because $t$ represents the variable of integration and the pair $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ indicates the limits of integration.